# Displaying Errors in PHP

Tags: php

I have php v5.3.2 on ubuntu 10.04. i changed the reporting options in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini to these:

```
display_errors = 1
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

I also added these lines to the top of my php files and restarted apache but im still not able to see the errors/warnings,

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Is there anything else in the way that prevents the errors from showing up?

Edit 1: According to phpinfo(), both display_errors and display_startup_errors are on.
The value of error_reporting is also 30719 which i'm not quite sure what it means.

Comment: Did you check the actual values of these configuration directives using `ini_get`?

Comment: run phpinfo() and see local values. what are they?

Comment: may be you're editing wrong  php.ini. phpifo() could help with that too - see ini file location

Comment: Yes i checked phpinfo and the display_errors is on.

Comment: As quick test try `set_error_handler("var_dump");` to find out if display_errors=0 is still the problem.

Comment: The only thing I hate more than ignorant questions is ignorant answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try error_reporting(-1); ?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel it's worth a try. According to the manual, it's the same as setting `E_ALL`.

Comment: wow it started working, Thanks alot man. Is there any logic behind why E_ALL was not working?

Comment: @Erfan nope, it worked because of other your moves and you still be able to see most of errors under E_ALL *if it's really set*

Comment: @optimystique nope it's not. **nothing is worth to try if coming from ignorance and guess work**

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Because nobody has EVER solved a puzzle by trying random illogical actions, right?

Comment: @jnpcl I'd say it's possible in theory. But it's injuring me when I see not a programmers but rather children at play

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Then why are you on a site where -anybody- can ask a question?

Comment: I am of romantic kind and if I help to born one programmer out of 100 000 lamers here, I'll be statisfied